# Is it possible to transform manually placed figure to code?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This website [www.mathcha.io](http://www.mathcha.io) converts mathematical drawings to code. Is there one for tikz? I would like to draw this figure somewhere then have the tikz code for it with e.g. example-image-a.

[image]

Comment: Converting a bitmap graphic to Ti*k*Z would require several steps: You'd need to trace the edges first to generate paths and get a vector graphic which you can then convert to Ti*k*Z format (e.g. using Inkscape). For simple images like the one you show, it might really be quicker (at least for someone who is somewhat familiar with Ti*k*Z) to draw this from scratch. It would probably also be more exact and require less code.

Comment: Mathcha can export to tikz code, it'll compile ok but the code it generates isn't particularly good tikz source.